# Alternative to Singleton in my Example?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, singleton, instance

I have an application written in Java. 
There I have a container class for all my GUI elements `MyForm` and I want to implement a class that provides a couple of methods to manipulate the Form `FormOperator`. For example disabling Buttons or writing dots into a TextPane.

Now many of those methods need the instances of the GUI element they want to operate on. For example a method `writeDots(JTextPane p)`

But in the next step I want to use the class `FormOperator` in a class that implements `Runnable`. So I had to pass the instance of the `JTextPane` to the class that implements Runnable and then the Runnable class passes it to the FormOperator class. But in my oppinion that isnt a proper way.

My Idea was to make the class `Form`a Singleton so I could get the instance of `Form`from the runnable class. And then I could create a method in the `Form`class `getTextPane()` in order to get the instance of the TextPane.

But as I read Singletons shouldn't be used either. So what would you recommend doing in this case.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english. :) But I hope you got tjhe point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a Singleton or some other pattern is appropriate depends on more information than you have given us.  "isn't a proper way" does not explain why you don't want to pass your container class to the Runnable instance to pass to the instance FormOperator.

Ask yourself what items there are in your program and what represents them, and whether their projected use matches patterns you're familiar with.  On the face of it, a singleton Form doesn't make any sense to me, but it might under special circumstances.  But just avoiding the passing of it in constructors and methods is no reason at all.

Sometimes in programming we get enamored of an idea we've had and figure out a way to make it work, instead of looking at the problem we're trying to solve and figuring out the best way to model that in code.  To be a software engineer, it isn't enough that you can make something work, it should be robust, as easy to maintain as is feasible, and flexible in the ways that you can predict it might need to be.

Comment: I want to say thank you for your answer at first. And you took up an important point for me. Surely it would be easy and straightforward to pass the instance around from class to class in the constructor. But it was more kind of a general question. Because I think this isn't a robust or flexible way to do it as the last class of this chain depends on 2 other classes. And I faced this problem multiple times, when I had to pass the instance of class forward and forward. And then I came to the question if there might be a more flexible and direct model.

Comment: So in what way is it more flexible?  For more 'direct', you're going to have to define what you mean by direct, and then decide if it is a desirable software engineering quality.  Machine language is much more direct, by several definitions, but that doesn't make it a good choice in general.  Singletons qualify as "side effects"; someone looking at the code for the caller cannot tell that the called routine is getting information somewhere else, and therefore it is harder to figure out what the call is doing.  Don't just say "isn't a robust or flexible way" -- reason out and articulate WHY.

Comment: Maybe I think of it in the wrong way and maybe this isnt a good example but sometimes you have to pass around an instance like 5 time or so. So firstly an issue is code because I think it is way harder to read when an instance is handled by so many classes. Thats what I mean with direct. Secondly: When you have to pass instances you often have to write constructors with multiple instances as parameters opposite generic constructor without so much parameters. (flexibility) And when you pass your instance 5 times chances are bigger that one of the classes throws exeception and the chain crashes.

Comment: There isn't anything "difficult" about passing parameters.  Singletons are actually an OO pattern of "global variables", shown to be software engineering problems in the 1960s.  If everything a routine deals with is in its signature, then looking at the call lets you know everything that is affected.  If it uses a singleton/global, the call doesn't show you that; it is a "hidden" effect.  How many times you pass a parameter has nothing to do with the likelihood of crashes; if you have a 'tramp' variable that gets passed around a lot, perhaps you need a better design, not a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons aren't good solution for numerous reasons, mainly because they are not much better than a global variable.
In your case using singleton would severely hurt reusability, since once you would need to display two instances of the same form at the same time, you would not be able to do it, since only on Form and FormOperator classes exist.

If I were you, at the first step I would instantiate the Form then pass it to a FormOperator as a constructor parameter:

```
public FormOperator(Form frm) {
    this.frm = Objects.requireNonNull(frm, "frm cannot be null");
}
```

Later it will need further refactorings. Applying the MVC pattern would be useful. Worthy reading: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Comment: thank you! Indeed I had problems with my english and it was hard to understand for me but it helped me out a lot, since I tried to implement something semilar (FormOperator = Controller) and never heard of MVC.